# Making Bandcamp iframe responsive - centering and overflow issues

Tags: css, iframe, center, responsive

I would like to have a responsive Bandcamp iframe using only CSS, as described [here](https://blog.theodo.com/2018/01/responsive-iframes-css-trick/) (and many other places). However, 2 issues:

1. If I enlarge my page to have a width greater than 700px, the iframe container starts expanding more than the Bandcamp iframe is capable. This pushes down the text below while the iframe stays the same size
2. The container is not centred once I reach this limit.

I think the logical solution is to somehow have a setting for when the device viewing the page has a width > 700 px to keep the iframe unresponsive, e.g.

```
if screen-width > 700px
   .responsive {
      width: 700px;
      ...
   }
else
   .responsive {
      width=100%;
      ...
   }
```

Is there a way of doing this? Or perhaps a more elegant solution?

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zg2cL06s/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1: `max-width`

Quickest way to constrain the width of your iframe without changing anything else would be to add a max-width property:

```css
.responsive iframe {
  max-width: 700px;
}
```

Here's an updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rjt6cbx/) demonstrating the max-width approach.

---

#### Solution 2: Media Query

Another way to accomplish this would be using a media query.

You would add something like this to constrain the width to 700px if screen width is greater than 700.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .responsive iframe {
    width: 700px;
  }
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78dm2w3L/) demonstrating the media query approach.

And here are some resources for learning more about media queries, which are really the bedrock of responsive web development.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

---

#### Edit: Centering

I missed your original requirement to have the iframe centered. I've updated both Fiddles with the centering approach I'd recommend which is to use `display: flex;`.

```css
.responsive {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here are some resources for using flex styles:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox
- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html

---

#### Note about iframes

While you can do some clever things with iframes, you should be aware that you cannot have a truly responsive experience with an embedded iframe unless you also control the code *inside* the iframe. In other words, without an explicit message being sent from the page loaded inside the iframe (which is almost never the case unless you built the page that the iframe is displaying and also built a mechanism to send messages back and forth), or without some seriously gnarly hacks, there is no obvious/clean way for the parent page to know anything about the content inside the iframe. So it's for all intents and purposes not possible (as far as I know) to calculate the size of the iframe content for laying out the parent page. With your Bandcamp example, the parent page has no way to know how tall the Bandcamp iframe needs to be at any given time in order for there to be no wasted space at the bottom of the iframe content. That's just an unfortunate reality of how iframes and browser security policies work.

---

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Made a few edits since I posted my answer. Hoping to make my answer more clear and offer some (hopefully) helpful links.

Comment: Updated my answer with info that addresses the centering requirement that I missed. Also added a note about iframes.

Comment: Oh, one more thing... in your example you don't need the `#main-content` rule since you don't have any elements on the page with that id, so it's not doing anything.

Comment: This is an amazingly complete answer, thank you so much! I hope this gets the upvotes it deserves.